# Touch two items on ListView

Tags: android, listview, multi-touch

A have a listview that sends elements to another listview. I'd like to let users touch two items of this list at the same time, and have both of this items sent to do other listview. I know how to pass the items through the listviews i just don't know how to handle clicking two items at the same time.

Also, when a set an onItemClickListener the android only invokes the method when the user remove the finger from the screen, is it possible to have this method called the exact time the finger touches the screen?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a limitation of Android before 3.x.

In 3.x, you can specify fragments which have their own listeners and everything else, so you could get two actions from two different views.

I think to implement this, you may have to do a bit of a hack involving multitouch and keeping track of where individual items are on the screen within the listview with View.getX() and view.getY().

In short, I don't think you can do this with onClickListeners, but you might be able to hack something together with GestureListeners using multitouch and explicitly keeping track of where items are on the list.

Perhaps you could have the users swipe over in order to select the items?  You could even animate it to make them feel like they're "throwing" the data to the next screen!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually, i'm doing this application to run only on 3.x, so a solution that works only for it would be enough. 

Tanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Do you know how to make this on 3.x?

Comment: You would have to have two ListViews side by side, each with their own  content (it could be the same content) and their own OnClickListeners.  You could register each OnClickListener to check if the other OnClickListener is currently engaged (do this by using view argument) and then perform your function according to the data selected.

Comment: That won't work for what i want. I need something that works like android keyboard, you can press two key at the same time and they will both be written on screen. well My list contains a maximum o 4 or 5 item so I guess that a table layout could work for me.

Comment: A table layout would work great for something like this.  [Here's an example of how to dynamically add rows to a tableLayout](http://en.androidwiki.com/wiki/Dynamically_adding_rows_to_TableLayout)

Comment: You need to make sure you're using the <merge> tag if you're using a custom view stub. :)

Comment: I've got it working using the onTouch method. It's not as simple  as i was expecting to be (because i'm getting the x and y positions of the touch, and calculating what items are being touched) but it's working very well. Do you have a good reference (other than the developers website) to read about the merge tag?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ListView.setChoiceMode(2) sets it to multiple choice.  It does this with a checkbox for each item.

I'm not sure of an event that fires on touch as opposed to touch-off.  Why do you need this handler?

Comment: I'm using chronometers so it would be good to have then stoped quick as possible.

Comment: I just tried this, its not what i wanted. I need to click two items from the list at the same time. In other words, two onItemClick() methods have to be invoked in "paralel".

Comment: Ok. What is the significance of executing the onItemClick in parallel?

Comment: Try to press two items in the same listview at the same time. Only one of the items will "feel" the touch.